# Ruby - Name Resolution Using a Variable

Tags: ruby, variables, module, namespaces

Is it possible to do something like this in Ruby:

```
var_1 = Module
var_2 = NestedModule

object = ::var_1::var_2::SomeObject.new # class resolves to ::Module::NestedModule::SomeObject
```

Though the above code does not work in Ruby, is there any alternative way to do this or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1):

First off, `NestedModule` is a bad name for a variable, in fact, it is actively misleading: the module isn't nested (there are no nested modules in Ruby), it's the *constant* that is nested.

In fact, that's precisely the confusion that leads to this question.

So, the constant `NestedModule` is nested inside the module referenced by the constant `Module`, which, however, because of your first line, is also accessible through the local variable `var_1`. (Remember, `Module`s are objects just like any other object!):

```
var_1 = Module
```

To get a reference to `NestedModule` in `var_2`, you can do:

```
var_2 = var_1::NestedModule
```

And lastly, to get a reference to `SomeObject`, you can do:

```
var_2::SomeObject.new
```

Comment: I have not posted the actual code, just enough to explain what I am trying to do. Plus, have you tested the code that you have posted? Because it does not work.

Comment: It works for me. Define "it does not work". What is the *exact* error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
klass  = Object.const_get("::#{var_1}::#{var_2}::Object")
object = klass.new
```

Comment: This is used to get values of simple constants, right? It's not working for class definitions.

Comment: Classes are objects just like any other objects, and a class definition is simply a shortcut to assigning an object to a constant. There is no such thing as "simple" and "non-simple" constants. There are just constants.